# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser как разложить по переменным?

Tags: php, парсер

Использую библиотеку PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. Хочу получить массив данных. С ссылки https://auto.ru/cars/used/sale/mercedes/e_klasse/1098608450-580b4296/ Делаю так:

```
        <?php
        $html = file_get_html('https://auto.ru/cars/used/sale/mercedes/e_klasse/1098608450-580b4296/');

                  foreach($html->find('span[class=CardInfo__cell]') as $card) {
                        echo $card->plaintext . '<br>';
                  }
          
        ?>
```

В итоге получаю текст (тип string)

> год выпуска
> 2015
> Пробег
> 78 568 км
> Кузов
> седан
> Цвет
> белый
> Двигатель
> 2.0 л / 184 л.с. / Бензин
> Налог
> 9 200 ₽ / год
> Коробка
> автоматическая
> Привод
> задний
> Руль
> Левый
> Состояние
> Не требует ремонта
> Владельцы
> 3 или более
> ПТС
> Дубликат
> Таможня
> Растаможен
> VIN
> WDD**************
> Госномер
> ******|750

Я хочу поместить каждую строчку в переменную или массив. То есть, $year = 2015, $probeg = 78 568 и так далее. То есть разделить каждое свойство авто в отдельную переменную. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать, если данные приходят как string? как правильно разложить это всё в переменные ?
**Заранее спасибо!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы несколько некорректно подходите к решению задачи. Необходимо взять не `plaintext` всей этой ерунды, а найти сам список `.CardInfo`. Далее у каждой строки списка есть соответствующий класс, по которому вы элементарно разложите все свойства.
что-то вроде такого

```
 $opts = ['year', 'kmAge'];
 $data = [];


 $ul = $html->find(".CardInfo",0);
 foreach($opts as $field){
     $data[$field] = $ul->find(".CardInfo__row_$field", 0)
                        ->find(".CardInfo__cell", 1)
                        ->plaintext;
 }
 print_r($data);
```